# How many guesses per second are possible against an encrypted disk?

Tags: security, encryption, disk-encryption, cryptography

I understand that guesses per second depends on the hardware and the encryption algorithm, so I don't expect an absolute number as answer.

For example, with an average machine you can make a lot (thousands?) of guesses per second for a hash created with a single md5 round, because md5 is fast, making brute force and dictionary attacks a real danger for most passwords.
But if instead you use bcrypt with enough rounds, you can slow the attack down to 1 guess per second, for example.

1) So how does disk encryption usually work?

This is how I imagine it, tell me if it is close to reality: When I enter the passphrase, it is hashed with a slow algorithm to generate a key (always the same?). Because this is slow, brute force is not a good approach to break it. Then, with the generated key, the disk is unencrypted on the fly very fast, so there is not a significant performance lose.

2) How can I test this with my own machine? I want to calculate the guesses per second my machine can make.

3) How many guesses per second are possible against an encrypted disk with the fastest PC ever so far?

Comment: I don't feel this is a very complete answer so I will leave a comment: 1) See [Shadok's answer](http://superuser.com/a/432465/25625) 2) Go find a free decryption program and run it and see how many per second it runs. 3) The fastest ever is classified as it is owned by the government for decrypting data received by the enemy. I don't know how fast it is but [$2 Billion](http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2012/03/ff_nsadatacenter/all/1) can buy you a lot of decryption power

Comment: The problem is verifying your results. How do you know the decrypted data is valid?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Usually the encrypted data for things like drive encryption will have a known header, if the header is gibberish then the key you tried was not the correct one.

Comment: @Scott What if I used multiple layers of encryption?

Comment: Then (if it has one) each layer has it's own header. Note I did not say ***all*** encryption methods have a header, only some do. And it is common for ones for disk encryption (not file encryption) to have a header.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: If you don't think your encryption algorithm is strong enough, you should change it, not put another insufficiently-strong band-aid on top of it and hope that it "adds up".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: How **I** encrypt my data is not relevant to my point. If I would hand you a hard drive right now, you could plug it into your computer and it would be detected as empty or corrupt. How would you even determine **if** it is encrypted? And if you attempt to decrypt it, with what approach? And how would you know it's the right approach and/or key? My goal was only to demonstrate that **this** question can not be answered in its current form, didn't want to start a debate. :)

Comment: If you want feedback on why the question was closed, please post on [meta], thank you.

Comment: "2) How can I test this with my own machine? I want to calculate the guesses per second my machine can make."  Be the happy developer you are, write a `for` loop, and see how many hashes per second you can do.  MD5 is *not* susceptible to brute force (there's 2^128 combinations, do the math).  Dictionary attacks have nothing to do with the speed of the encryption algorithm, it has to do with the common passkey being in a known list.

Comment: Oh, and the math.  Let's say I can do 1 billion MD5 hashes/second (highly unlikely for a consumer computer as of 2012).  It would take: ((2^128)/(1 billion hashes/second))/(60 secs/min * 60 mins/hour * 24 hours/day * 365 days/year) ~= 1.08 x 10^22 years.  Even if you could manage to do a quadrillion hashes per second, it would still take 10 quadrillion years...

Comment: @Breakthrough That's not what I asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you have to decrypt to be assured you have the right password is the header and its checksum.

You can just cut the first X bytes (as you only need the header) and throw passwords at it in RAM, thus speeding up the cracking many times.
The good password is the one which decrypts a valid header with a good checksum and you can then re-use it for the full disk, however you have to know the header structure beforehand for this to work.